# Print specific DIV with CSS using jqprint

Tags: javascript, html, css, jqprint

I want to print a div with css. Its working with me when I apply `inline css` but in `external and internal css` its not working. Below is my code,

```
<script src="jquery.jqprint.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#PrintButton").click( function() {
      $('#divToPrint').jqprint();
      return false;
  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
@media screen,print
  {
  .test {background:#0F0; width:500px; height:200px;}
  }
</style>

<input id="PrintButton" type="button" name="Print" value="Print" />

<div id="divToPrint" class="test">
Print Me, I'm in DIV
</div>
```

Comment: Dont use `<style></style>` after `<script></script>`.It should be before.

Comment: @Zword It doesn't matter but I put it before and still not working

Comment: I am not telling that its the solution .Its the correct order to use those tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried your code, it seems to be working fine with external CSS.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.jqprint-0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#PrintButton").click( function() {
      $('#divToPrint').jqprint();
      return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="PrintButton" type="button" name="Print" value="Print" />

<div id="divToPrint" class="test">
Print Me, I'm in DIV
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

and external css file name : **test.css**

```
@media screen,print
{
  .test {
            background:#0F0; width:500px; height:200px;
        }
}
```

Comment: Its strange, it was not working before and now working with me also perfectly. Thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: I got this error -- Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined

Comment: I also get the error Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined, possibly due to the plugin not supporting new versions of jQuery.